# Possible to Run Crystal Reports from SSIS and export to PDF?

Tags: sql-server-2008, pdf, ssis, crystal-reports

There's a legacy VB6 application at my company that allows reports to be emailed to clients. Basically, a requisition number is entered, and after QC to make sure it's valid, the appropriate Crystal Reports template is called, exported to PDF, and emailed to the correct contact. I've been asked to research the feasibility of converting this from the current manual task (enter the requisition number and click the "Email Report" button) to a SQL Agent job, most likely an SSIS package. Duplicating the SQL that currently validates the requisitions is no problem, but I don't know how to get SSIS to call the Crystal Reports template (or if it's even possible), or how to then export it to PDF to be emailed.

The Crystal Reports templates are highly customized and have their own SQL queries that use the requisition number as the parameter. There are several templates for each client, so there are many templates existing (literally hundreds), and recreating all that customization isn't feasible. That's why I need to use the existing Crystal Reports instead of another option. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Crystal reports 10. I have no ability to change this.

Is it possible to invoke a Crystal Reports template from SSIS and then export it to PDF, and if so, how? Any advice or links to resources will be very welcome!

Comment: I have a situation a bit similar to your case, but it relies on how your reporting application was designed. Basically I stored crystal report template path and parameters into the database, In SSIS we used execute process task to call our reporting application with arguments to generate local copy of the report, then send the report through.

Comment: Interesting. I'll see if that works for one of ours as a test.

Comment: cqi, can you give me an example of the arguments you passed to the report? I'm having trouble finding information on that.

Comment: Hi JeffK627, the arguments should be defined in your reporting application. Suppose you have a console program can accept input parameters, then the console program validates and passes these parameters into the crystal report. So as I said, it really depends on how your reporting application designed.

Comment: Thanks cqi. I just realized (after two days of head scratching) that I could base the console program on the existing VB6 legacy application by stripping out all the user interaction. D'oh!